# Is there any way to create a TCP server in chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Instead of running a TCP server in native messaging host application, is it possible to run a TCP sever directly in chrome extension's background page and listen on localhost?

Comment: No, extensions can't do it.

Comment: thanks [wOxxOm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3959875/woxxom), is it possible to connect to a tcp server for raw data communication(not http)?

Comment: Extensions don't have a special API for this. Try using WebSockets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extension cannot run tcp server, it can talk to external server by http or websocket. Thanks to [wOxxOm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3959875/woxxom)